# In hibernate, do I need to initialize associate in class definition?

Tags: hibernate

I define a user class in hibernate. User has an address.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Do I need to initialize address like below?

```
private Address address = new Address();
```

It seems either works. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

In My opinion this depend on your **requirements**!!

- If a `User` cannot exist without an `Address` then **YES**,
- Otherwise a `null` Address would be the best way to represent the outside world that you DO NOT KNOW any `Address` of the `User`.
- Collections (List,Set,Collection,Bag) could be set to Empty Collection so that you dont have to check for `null` as the underlying nature of Hibernate does not distinguish between a `null` Collection association and an empty one. Check [Jboss Hibernate Reference documentation here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-persistent)

Comment: An empty address really isn't an indication of knowing anything about an address, though. To me, they seem equivalent logically, but I think a null address is a little more obvious.